# Windows Batch File to remove certain tags in an XML

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an xml file similar to the one below, in which i would like to delete all the xml tags of slide 
 including their child elements and keep the parent tags as shown below using windows
 batch file. any help on this pls!

**Existing Code :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slideshow title="Sample Slide Show" date="Date of publication" author="Yours Truly">

<slide type="all">
    <title>Wake up to WonderWidgets!</title>
</slide>

<slide type="all">
    <title>Overview</title>
    <item>
    Why
    <em>WonderWidgets</em>
    are great
    </item>
    <item/>
    <item>
    Who
    <em>buys</em>
    WonderWidgets
    </item>
</slide>

</slideshow>
```

**Required Code**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slideshow title="Sample Slide Show" date="Date of publication" author="Yours Truly">

</slideshow>
```

Comment: What about your efforts?

Comment: Sorry Abhi, I was new to this batch scripting about XML files, so that posted here. Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SKIP=FALSE
SET NEEDLE=slideshow

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN (input.xml) DO (
    IF !SKIP! EQU FALSE ECHO %%i
    SET INPUT=%%i

    SET DATA=!INPUT:~1,9!
    IF !DATA! EQU !NEEDLE! SET SKIP=TRUE
    SET DATA=!INPUT:~2,9!
    IF !DATA! EQU !NEEDLE! SET SKIP=FALSE
)

IF !SKIP! EQU FALSE ECHO !INPUT!

ENDLOCAL
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "print=1"
    (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("input.xml"
        ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=/<> " %%b in ("%%a"
        ) do if /i "%%~b"=="slide" (
            if defined print (set "print=") else (set "print=1")        
        ) else if defined print echo(%%a
    ) > "output.xml"
```

It just read the first tag in the line, that is used as a switch to determine if the line must be written to output or not.

Answer (score 0):

You really should be using a tool that is built for processing XML.

But it is not too difficult to provide a solution using a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) that performs a regular expression search/replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. REPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

A solution using REPL.BAT will be much more robust and faster than any pure batch solution.

If there are no abbreviated empty slide tags (no `<slide\>` or `<slide attribute="value"/>`), then the following should work:

```
type input.xml|repl "\s*<slide(\s[^>]*)?>([\s\S](?!</slide>))*[\s\S]</slide>" "" m >output.xml
```

If there may be abbreviated empty slide tags, then the following more complicated regex should work:

```
type input.xml|repl "\s*<slide((\s[^>]*?)?/>|(\s[^>]*)?>([\s\S](?!</slide>))*[\s\S]</slide>)" "" m >output.xml
```